# How to restrict passwordless file sharing in Win10 to only allowed hosts

Tags: windows-10, networking, file-sharing, windows-firewall

I need to keep password less sharing enabled but i would like to restrict it to just certain hosts.

Is it possible to use the Windows Firewall to block all incoming share connection / protocols unless its coming from a lists of approved hosts?